# Special character is converted to ? in React Quill Editor

Tags: reactjs, next.js, rich-text-editor, react-quill

I am trying to add special character like ∑, Ω or ∞ in React quill editor. But during saving the content inside DB, these special character converted to ? character.
For your reference I am using below version:
"react-quill": "^2.0.0"

I have used Mac short cut key to insert the special character but no luck.

Comment: You haven't asked an actual question. Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: *during saving the content inside DB* - what do you mean by DB? Do you use a separate database?

Comment: I am using React js in client side while in backend REST API is bult in Node js with express js framework with Sequalize ORM, where i am saving the quill editor contents inside the table